# Gender of person who sings Bleach's eleventh opening (Anima Rossa)?

Tags: bleach, theme-song

My favourite Bleach song is the eleventh opening: *Anima Rossa* by Porno Graffiti. My sister, who is a big fan of Bleach, says it's a male who sings it. I, who is only on episode 86, believes it is a female. It just sounds like one.

Despite the song *sounding* as though a female sings it, I too have reasons to believe it is sung by a male. My reason is because, I remember noticing that Fullmetal Alchemist's (2003 series; not Brotherhood) first opening theme-Melissa- is also by Porno Graffiti... but the singer is audibly male. You can just ***tell***. Although, I don't want to believe a **MALE** sings Anima Rossa.

I need to know, because I imagine certain characters singing my favourite anime songs (but the character has to be from the same anime as the song :P ), and I imagined Rangiku singing it. I have no idea why; I just did (and still do). But if it's a male who sings it... I have to change that.

I'd appreciate it if you could give me unquestionable evidence.

Comment: FWIW, the vocals on "Anima Rossa" sound unmistakeably male to me (granted, in a somewhat high register). I think your ear might not be tuned to Japanese voices quite right.

Comment: I shouldn't HAVE to "tune my ear to Japanese voices". Knowing the gender isn't quite necessary enough for me to do that when I'm American. This is the only time I had to because 1. I love this song and 2. my sister and I had a debate over it. You thinking it sounds male is your opinion. I just don't hear it your way (and your comment was kind of a waste because... that was completely unhelpful).

Comment: I don't know why you're so bothered about this. I'm just pointing out that the reason you had this question is not that Porno Graffiti's vocalist has an ambiguous-sounding voice, but rather that there's an issue with the way you're perceiving it.

Comment: Well, you don't have to point out the reason why I posted it, because I already know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porno_Graffitti)

> Porno Graffitti (ポルノグラフィティ Poruno Gurafiti), also known as Porno (ポルノ Poruno) is a Japanese **male rock band** from Innoshima, Hiroshima Prefecture, Japan.

Current and Past Members only lists 3 names and Wikipedia only has a link to the past member [Masami Shiratama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masami_Shiratama) which says:

> After leaving the band in June 2004, **he** released the album Great Pleasure in December 2005.

[Akihito Okano](http://www.generasia.com/wiki/Okano_Akihito) (who does vocals) and [Haruichi Shindō](http://www.generasia.com/wiki/Shindo_Haruichi) (who does background vocals) have profiles on generasia and both lists to have wives. Considering that same-sex marriage [is not legal in japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-sex_marriage_in_Japan) and their images on generasia look like men, I would conclude that your sister is correct and that it is a Male singing it.

If you are still in doubt, I checked to see if I could find a live performance of Anima Rossa on Youtube and [here is the Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhhPUV_ckvc)

Comment: though i have never heard Anima Rossa (yet) i can't imagine Rangiku singing it, then again i watched the Dub Version of Bleach so i have Rangiku's English Voice Actor's voice in my head

Comment: I didn't go by her voice. xD I went by her looks, the song's lyrics, and the way the song sounds, and it seems to fit her. You should listen to the song. Here's the link to the full, non-live version: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bu3Mks22PtQ). And the lyrics (look at the English... but take the word "men" out and add "women". THEN it fits): [link](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/bleach/animarossa.htm). Hmm... I guess "men" being there is more proof that it was sung by a male.      ._.